# Simultaneous reduction to pseudo-permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

In my research (theoretical physics) I've come across a mathematical problem that has so far stumped to me, my colleagues and my ability to google things, so I'm interested in seeing if anyone here has an answer.

---

First, let me make a definition: an $m\times m$ matrix $M$ is an $n$-*pseudopermutation* for some positive integer $n$ if $M^n=I$ and each row and column of $M$ contains exactly one nonzero element, which is an $n$th root of unity. This generalises permutation matrices, where the roots of unity are limited to 1.

Now, consider a finite set of matrices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ who have the property $A_i^n=I$ (the positive integer $n$ is the same for all $i$). The matrices do not necessarily commute, but $(A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\cdots A_{i_\ell})^n=I$ holds for any sequence of indices $\{i_1,i_2,\ldots i_\ell\}$ (this property is of course guaranteed if they do commute).

**My question is then this: does there always exist an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}A_i P$ is an $n$-pseudopermutation for all $i$? If so, how does one go about finding $P$?** (When the matrices commute, this reduces to simultaneous diagonalisation.)

---

---

I have successfully done this for some $9\times 9$ matrices that showed up in my research, but it was quite *ad hoc* and didn't amount to a general method. Still, I'll write an example in case it helps inspire some answers. I'll keep the physics to a minimum since I'm appealing to the higher court of pure mathematics, but if you're interested, the full context can be found in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.13684).

An $N$-particle scattering process can be described using $N$ momenta $p_i$. This isn't very convenient, though, since the vectors aren't Lorentz invariant and don't make conservation of momentum very manifest. Therefore, it's convenient to define *generalized Mandelstam invariants*  $s_{ijk\cdots} = (p_i+p_j+p_k+\ldots)^2$, which makes them Lorentz invariant, and conservation of momentum (i.e. $\sum_i p_i = 0$) is replaced by linear relations among the invariants, so by choosing a suitable basis on the space they span means you can stop worrying about such things altogether.

For $N=6$, a convenient basis is $\{s_{12},s_{23},s_{34},s_{45},s_{56},s_{61},s_{123},s_{234},s_{345}\}$.
It has the added benefit of being closed under cyclic permutations of the set $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_6\}$, i.e. those cyclings act as permutations on this set of invariants. This makes writing down and manipulating any Lorentz-invariant function of the momenta that has this cyclic symmetry very convenient.

However, I also have to work with functions that have other symmetries. One is symmetric under cyclic permutations of $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ and $\{p_4,p_5,p_6\}$, as well as under swapping these two subsets. This is a problem, because the basis is not closed --- for instance, the cycling $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}\mapsto\{p_2,p_3,p_1\}$ maps $s_{34}\rightarrow s_{14}$ which is not an element of the basis (instead, it is the linear combination $s_{56}-s_{123}-s_{234}+s_{23}$). The expressions become messy and the symmetry becomes hidden.

As a remedy, I seek a new basis that is closed under the different symmetry operations. In this case, the symmetry group is generated by $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}\mapsto\{p_2,p_3,p_1\}$ and $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6\}\mapsto\{p_4,p_5,p_6,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$. On the space of invariants with the old basis, these act as the linear transformations (zero elements omitted)
\begin{equation}
 A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
  &1&&&&&&&\\
  -1&-1&&&&&1&&\\
  &1&&&1&-1&-1&&\\
  &&&1&&&&&\\
  &&&&1&&&&\\
  &&&&&1&&&\\
  &&&&&&1&\\
  -1&&-1&&1&&&-1&\\
  &1&&1&&-1&-1&&\\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad A_2=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   &&&1&&&&&\\
   &&&&1&&&&\\
   &&&&&1&&&\\
   1&&&&&&&&\\
   &1&&&&&&&\\
   &&1&&&&&&\\
   &&&&&&1&&\\
   &&&&&&&1&\\
   &&&&&&&&1\\
 \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
respectively. This is an example of the set of matrices described above, and only the latter is a (pseudo)permutation. To find a better basis, I drew a Cayley graph mapping out how these generators transform all invariants of the type $s_{ij}$ or $s_{ijk}$ ($ij(k)$ indicates $s_{ij(k)}$; dashed lines indicate $A_2$ and solid triangles counterclockwise indicate $A_1$):

Then I used the graph to find sets of invariants that transformed into each other under the group (the ones I ended up with are marked with $\star,\circ$ and $\bullet$, respectively). Lastly, I played around with linear combinations taken from the sets until I found one that gave a complete basis. This last step was very trial and error and the main reason for looking for a better way. The result was
\begin{equation}
 \begin{gathered}
  t_1 = -\frac{s_{36} + s_{14} + s_{25}}{3},\quad
  t_2 = -\frac{s_{24} + s_{35} + s_{16}}{3},\quad
  t_3 = -\frac{s_{15} + s_{26} + s_{34}}{3},\\
  t_6 = \frac{s_{36} + \omega s_{14} + \omega^2 s_{25}}{3},\quad
  t_4 = \frac{s_{24} + \omega s_{35} + \omega^2 s_{16}}{3},\quad
  t_5 = \frac{s_{15} + \omega s_{26} + \omega^2 s_{34}}{3},\\
  t_9 = \frac{\omega^2 s_{36} + \omega s_{14} + s_{25}}{3},\quad
  t_7 = \frac{\omega^2 s_{24} + \omega s_{35} + s_{16}}{3},\quad
  t_8 = \frac{\omega^2 s_{15} + \omega s_{26} + s_{34}}{3},
 \end{gathered} 
\end{equation}
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$. Defining $P$ as the transformation that takes $\{s_{12},\ldots\}\mapsto\{t_1,\ldots\}$, both $A_1$ and $A_2$ become 3-pseudopermutations:
\begin{equation}
    P^{-1} A_1P = \begin{bmatrix}
        &1&&&&&&&\\
        &&1&&&&&&\\
        1&&&&&&&&\\
        &&&&\omega&&&&\\
        &&&&&\omega&&&\\
        &&&\omega&&&&&\\
        &&&&&&&\omega^2&\\
        &&&&&&&&\omega^2\\
        &&&&&&\omega^2&&\\
    \end{bmatrix},\qquad
    P^{-1} A_2P = \begin{bmatrix}
        1&&&&&&&&\\
        &&1&&&&&&\\
        &1&&&&&&&\\
        &&&1&&&&&\\
        &&&&&1&&&\\
        &&&&1&&&&\\
        &&&&&&1&&\\
        &&&&&&&&1\\
        &&&&&&&1&\\
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
I have done the same when the symmetry is cyclings of $\{p_1,p_2\}$ and $\{p_3,\ldots,p_6\}$ and cyclings/swaps of $\{p_1,p_2\},\{p_3,p_4\},\{p_5,p_6\}$, which was sufficient for everything I needed to accomplish, but it bugs me that I couldn't do it more elegantly. With $N=8$ one would be dealing with $20\times 20$ matrices, so the same hand-fiddly approach is not really practical there.